# Do Android's XML files do the same thing as iOS Xcode's storyboard?

Tags: android, ios, xml, android-studio, uistoryboard

Are Android's XML files in Android Studios same as iOS version of Xcode's Storyboards, ones where you create the visual design of your app?

Answer (score 1):

The layout xml files do.  They're far more readable and editable than iOS's storyboards though.  The norm in android is to design in xml, the GUI editor is not only harder to use, but its far slower to use-  someone who know's what they're doing can write the xml for a design in half the time it would take to drag, drop, and tediously adjust like in xcode.  What the layout files don't do is transitions-  those are in code.

Other xml files do other things (hold string constants, color constants, styles, etc).

Comment: FWIW, [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) provides a similar capability for iOS. It allows you to build native iOS apps using a human-readable XML markup language, similar to Android (or XAML, if you are familiar with .NET development).